# Jest / React Testing Library, So Many Errors

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm new to React Testing Library and Jest. I could successfully run a simple set of tests on it, like the below,
but when I tried to test on my "App.js", where a lot of imports/requires, it started to get a many set of errors on the each `import`, and I'm tbh overwhelmed.

Here's a working example:

- ./src/dev/test/AppTmp.js

```js
import React from "react";

export const Topbar = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>hoge.</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

- ./src/__tests__/hello.js

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import React from 'react'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import * as renderer from "react-test-renderer";

import { Topbar }  from '../dev/test/AppTmp'

test('tmp test.', () => {
  const component = renderer.create(
    <Topbar />,
  );
  let tree = component.toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

The above successfully runs.

A problem is when I add an import line like this:

- ./src/dev/test/AppTmp.js

```js
import React from "react";

import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'; // <--- added this

export const Topbar = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>hoge.</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

- ./src/__tests__/hello.js

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import React from 'react'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import * as renderer from "react-test-renderer";

import { Topbar }  from '../dev/test/AppTmp'

test('tmp test.', () => {
  const component = renderer.create(
    <Topbar />,
  );
  let tree = component.toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

The above, with just an extra import line, causes the following error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    ...
    ...

    Details:

    /home/user/pg/react/myapp/node_modules/react-markdown/index.js:6
    export {uriTransformer} from './lib/uri-transformer.js'
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      24 | import "prismjs/themes/prism-tomorrow.css";
      25 | import { LoremIpsum } from "react-lorem-ipsum";
    > 26 | import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
         | ^
      27 |
      28 | export const Topbar = () => {
      29 |   return (

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1796:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (dev/test/AppTmp.js:26:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total
```

(note: actually I had more lines as showing above, but what I'm doing is essentially the same, so kindly ignore them)

So this is an `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'` error. Well, At first I thought I'm going to solve the error on SO or Google. But the error hell continues...

Now I added a different line as the following.

- ./src/dev/test/AppTmp.js

```js
import React from "react";

// import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
import Slider from "react-slick"; // <--- added this

export const Topbar = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>hoge.</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

The above caused an error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    matchMedia not present, legacy browsers require a polyfill

      25 | import { LoremIpsum } from "react-lorem-ipsum";
      26 | // import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
    > 27 | import Slider from "react-slick";
         | ^
      28 | import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
      29 | import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
      30 | import 'bootstrap';

      at new MediaQueryDispatch (../node_modules/enquire.js/src/MediaQueryDispatch.js:15:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/enquire.js/src/index.js:2:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/react-slick/lib/slider.js:50:53)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/react-slick/lib/index.js:8:38)
      at Object.<anonymous> (dev/test/AppTmp.js:27:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/hello.js:8:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total
```

This time I got an `matchMedia not present, legacy browsers require a polyfill` error.

Error hell continues. Next I tried:

- ./src/dev/test/AppTmp.js

```js
import React from "react";

// import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
// import Slider from "react-slick"; 
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'; // <--- added this

export const Topbar = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>hoge.</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    ...
    ...

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /home/user/pg/react/myapp/node_modules/nanoid/index.browser.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { urlAlphabet } from './url-alphabet/index.js'
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      49 | // import uniqueId from 'lodash/utility/uniqueId'
      50 | import _ from 'lodash'
    > 51 | import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
         | ^
      52 | import { WithContext as ReactTags } from 'react-tag-input';
      53 |
      54 | const mymodules = require("./../../mymodules.js")

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1796:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (dev/test/AppTmp.js:51:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total
```

This time, got an error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. What the hell is going on.....

---

- ./.babelrc

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "loose": true,
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "browsers": "last 2 chrome versions"
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            "loose": true,
            "modules": false
          }
        ],
        "@babel/preset-react"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

- ./package.json

```json
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    },
    "transform": {
      "\\.[jt]sx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "tsx"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?![@autofiy/autofiyable|@autofiy/property]).+\\.js$",
      "/node_modules/(?![@autofiy/autofiyable|@autofiy/property]).+\\.ts$",
      "/node_modules/(?![@autofiy/autofiyable|@autofiy/property]).+\\.tsx$",
      "/node_modules/(?!my-package)(.*)",
      "/node_modules/(?!@ngrx|(?!deck.gl)|ng-dynamic)"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
  },
```

---

So, what's the best thing I can do now?

actually I've been taking 8 hours so far on Jest to get the above-mentioned simple example working, I didn't expect just a testing development environment building is this damn hard way.

I mean I think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. that's why I'm getting this many errors no? What's not right with this setup, can I ask a help? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have `{ "loose": true, "modules": false }` in your `.babelrc`?

Comment: Because 1. I copy pasted from SO or Google 2. When I remove the lines it gets an error. Sorry, but I'm not familiar with the options. Do you mean the options is/may be the cause of the problems?

Comment: Yes, you have modules disabled yet you're trying to use them, hence the error: `Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

Comment: Should I remove the lines? Or should I replace "false" to "true"?

Comment: Unfortunately I changed it to `[
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            "loose": true
          }
        ],`tried again, I got the same error `Cannot use import statement outside a module` on the `nanoid` import.